# Boolean parameters for python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Do I need to use an elif for this question? How do I go about it?
Sorry for the mega noob question.

```
def hint1(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    ''' (bool, bool, bool, bool) -> bool
    Return True iff at least one of the boolen parameters 
    p1, p2, p3, or p4 is True. 
    >>> hint1(False, True, False, True)
    True
    '''
```

Comment: `def hint1(*args): return any(args)`

Comment: Seriously, what learning materials have you been provided? This is a basic question, and your learning materials should contain the answers you need.

Answer (score 4):

```
def hint1(*args):
    return any(args)
```

The [`any`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#any) function takes an iterable, and returns `True` if any element of the it is true.

The problem is that `any` takes an iterable, not a bunch of separate values.

That's what the `*args` is for. It takes all of your arguments and puts them together in a tuple that's fed into your single parameter. You can then pass that tuple to `any` as your iterable. See [Arbitrary Argument Lists](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) in the tutorial for more details.

---

As Elazar points out, this doesn't work for exactly 4 arguments, it works for *any* number of arguments (even 0). Whether that's better or worse depends on your use case.

If you want to get an error on 3 arguments or 5, you could of course add an explicit test:

```
if len(args) != 4:
    raise TypeError("The number of arguments thou shalt count is "
                    "four, no more, no less. Four shall be the "
                    "number thou shalt count, and the number of "
                    "the counting shall be four. Five shalt thou "
                    "not count, nor either count thou three, "
                    "excepting that thou then proceed to four. Six "
                    "is right out.")
```

But really, it's much simpler to just use a static argument list for that case.

Comment: +1, with one difference from the original question - it does not enforce "4 arguments exactly".

Comment: @Elazar: But the original question doesn't state that requirement anywhere.

Comment: +1 - For using `*args`

Comment: I don't know if it's an actual requirement, but technically it does - by the argument list.

Answer (score 1):

About as short as you can get...

```
def hint1(p1,p2,p3,p4):
    return any([p1,p2,p3,p4])
```

Comment: `hint1 = lambda *x : any(x)`. shorter :P

Answer (score 0):

The [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#any) method takes a single iterable and returns true if any element is true.

```
def hint1(p1, p2, p3, p4):
    return any([p1, p2, p3, p4])
```

Answer (score -2):

You might try

```
def hint1(p1,p2,p3,p4):
    if p1 or p2 or p3 or p4:
        return True
```

Or

```
def hint1(p1,p2,p3,p4)
    if p1:
        return True
    if p2:
        return True
    if p3:
        return True
    if p4:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: or `return p1 or p2 or p3 or p4`. but `any` is the right thing.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't learned the any function in class yet, so this is most helpful!